# Insert rows into Hive as they are computed in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Let's say I want to build a Spark application that I want to be able to kill part way through. I still want to persist the data from the partitions that finish successfully. I attempt to do so by inserting it into a Hive table. In (PySpark) pseudocode:

```
def myExpensiveProcess(x):
 ...

udfDoExpensiveThing = udf(myExpensiveProcess, StringType())

myDataFrame \
  .repartition(100) \
  .withColumn("HardEarnedContent", udfDoExpensiveThing("InputColumn")) \
  .write.insertInto("SomeExistingHiveTable")
```

I run this until 30 partitions are done, then I kill the job. When I check `SomeExistingHiveTable`, I see that it has no new rows.

How do I persist the data that finishes, irrespective of which ones did not?

Comment: Are you sure the data exists in the Hive table location?

Comment: If I let the task finish, the Hive table is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and desired behavior ensuring consistency of the output.

Write data directly to file system bypassing Spark's data source API.

```
myDataFrame \
  .repartition(100) \
  .withColumn("HardEarnedContent", udfDoExpensiveThing("InputColumn")) \
  .rdd \
  .foreachPartition(write_to_storage)
```

where `write_to_storage` implements required logic, for example using [one of the HDFS interfaces](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/).

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to write it to Hive, without connecting to Hive manually using JDBC?

Comment: @David Spark uses Thrift to connect to HiveServer2, not JDBC. Actually, it directly uses the metastore